# need to know, using jquery, when a razor view is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've a razor partial view that contains a bootstrap panel. It is loaded in a modal window using jquery. The view should have, by design, both the heading and the footer sections visible all the time and the body section should be scrollable. I'm able to accomplish this by setting the height of the div class=panel-body to for example, 400px, but I would like to set it in jquery before the modal opens, to a value determined according to the height of the modal window, which I know how to get it. My question is how to apply it to the body section, dynamically using jquery? Or, in other words: How can I detect when this specific view is loaded?

```
RoomingList.cshtml

<div id="panelRoomingList" class="panel panel-primary nopadding">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div id="panelBody" class="panel-body" style="height:400px; overflow-y:scroll">
       </div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center" style="margin-top:30px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: Pseudo script for ilustration only.
It has been shortened for simplicity, please ignore any code errors, if any. The original works as expected.

```
function ShowRoomingList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: ShowRoomingListUrl,
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
      $("#modal_RoomingList").modal("show");
      $("#modal_RoomingList").html(data);
    }
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, exception) { 
    DisplayAjaxError(xhr, status, exception); }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can get to know that this load is being loaded in the `success` function of ajax call right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ajax success` function (where you are showing model dialog) to set the dynamic properties (in your case height) to the modal dialog.